# Retrieving a word from a string literal?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

In NASM I have `strconst_0 dw 5, 0, __utf16__('hello')` (with single backticks) as a string

I'm trying to access the 'h' like this (where [ebp+8] is 0 and [ebp+4] is the address of the string)

```
mov eax, [ebp+8] ; get the index
mov ebx, [ebp+4] ; get the address
movzx eax, word [ebx + 2 * eax + 4]
push eax
call print_char ; call the print function
```

However, when I run this code, only an empty character is printed

EDIT: Full listing

```
main:
pop edx
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 4
mov [ebp-4], edx
mov eax, strconst_0
push eax
push dword 0
call getChar
add esp, 8
push eax
call printChar
add esp, 4
mov edx, [ebp-4]
add esp, 4
pop ebp
push edx
ret

getChar:
pop edx
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 4
mov [ebp-4], edx
mov eax, [ebp+8]
mov ebx, [ebp+4]
movzx eax, word [ebx + 2 * eax + 4]
push eax
pop eax
mov edx, [ebp-4]
add esp, 4
pop ebp
push edx
ret
```

Comment: OT, but, why so much code to calculate the address? Especially that double-width mul.. how about `movzx eax, word [ebx + 2 * eax + 4]`

Comment: Didn't know you could do that with an address

Comment: Nice, right? But that doesn't solve this problem of course, and I don't know what's wrong

Comment: can you post a self contained text rather than a random snippet, it would be much easier to answer.

Comment: @Dmitry - Added the full listing

Comment: Ill give it a shot in an hour.

Comment: That `pop edx` when entering a function seems odd

Comment: I was gonna say that. What system are you writing this on/for?

Comment: I'm writing this on bare x86. Also I use the pop edx and stuff at the start of the function to preserve the return address (inefficiently heh)

Comment: You can just leave it on the stack right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the arguments the wrong way around. If I swap ebx and eax in the inital mov instructions, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. you pop the return address of main into edx at start of your program, this makes no sense.
2. you have no comments at all, so I cannot possible understand what you are trying to do, as you have no prototype for your getChar.

basically, here's analysis, I do not have the tools on me so I made a few assumptions

```
main:
    ; why is return address of main popped into edx?
    pop        edx

    ; standard stack setup                   
    push       ebp
    mov        ebp,      esp

    ; make space for 4 bytes
    sub        esp,      4

    ; store edx in where return address used to be... why?
    mov        [ebp-4],  edx

    ; move address of strconst_0 to eax
    mov        eax,      strconst_0

    ; push eax on stack
    push       eax

    ; push 4 bytes 0x00000000 on stack
    push dword 0

    ; call getchar(0, strconst_0)
    call       getChar

    ; restore stack
    add        esp,      8

    ; push eax which was mutated in getChar on stack
    push       eax

    ; printChar(eax)
    call       printChar

    ; restore stack
    add        esp,      4

    ; move whatever we overwritten old return address to, to edx
    mov        edx,      [ebp-4]

    ; restore stack
    add        esp,      4
    pop        ebp

    ; restore return address
    push       edx

    ; return
    ret

; what do I accept(on stack)
; what do I return(in eax)
getChar:
    ; again, seems silly
    pop edx

    ; obvious
    push ebp
    mov        ebp,      esp

    ; make space for 4 bytes on stack
    sub        esp,      4

    ; overwrite return address with edx
    mov        [ebp-4],  edx

    ; I am guessing you are trying to get the two arguments into eax, ebx

    ; eax = 0
    mov        eax,      [ebp+8]
    ; ebx = strconst_0
    mov        ebx,      [ebp+4]
    ; magic is here
    movzx      eax,      word [ebx + 2 * eax + 4]
    ; push magic number
    push       eax
    ; pop ... something into eax
    pop        eax
    ; restore edx from whatever you put there...
    mov        edx,      [ebp-4]
    ; restore stack?
    add        esp,      4

    ; obvious
    pop        ebp
    push       edx
    ret
```

Honestly, I have no idea what you are doing, it would help if you say something along the lines of
"I am trying to make a function which accepts a ? and the address of the string buffer, which ?"

In particular,
1. I have no idea what getChar inputs are, is it position of character? is it something else?
2. I have no idea what getChar outputs are, does it store something in eax? does it launch the missiles?
3. I have no idea why you use your function's return address for temporary storage, it is silly.

```
main:
    push           ebp
    mov            ebp,                esp

    ; getChar(0, str)
    push           str
    mov dword      eax,                0
    push           eax
    call           getChar
    add            esp,                8

    ; printChar(str)
    push           str
    call           printChar
    add            esp,                4

    mov            esp,                ebp
    pop            ebp
    ret

; char getChar(long ix, char *str)
; returns: char at index indicated by ix in eax register
getChar:
    push           ebp
    mov            ebp,                esp
    push           ebx   ; save ebx to avoid unwanted side-effects

    mov            eax,                [ebp + 8]    ; ix
    mov            ebx,                [ebp + 12]   ; str
    add            eax,                ebx    ; eax = &(str[ix])
    mov            eax,                (eax)  ; eax = *eax = str[ix]

    pop            ebx  ; restore ebx
    mov            esp,                ebp
    pop            ebp
    rts

str db 'this is a string.', 0
```

This is definitely not going to work, and given purely for demonstrational purposes since I have not written x86 in a while, the idea should be clear though. Hope it helps.

Comment: getChar accepts a 32-bit pointer to the string literal and an index to the character. The characters are 2 bytes each (UTF-16) and have to be prefixed by a dword holding the size. getChar then puts the character at the index passed in eax before returning.

Comment: Same idea except you will need to multiply(or shift) the index value so that it is multiplied by two (address of string + 2 * position), that will be your character position. Then you move 16 bytes(so a word, not a byte) from this pointer to your eax as a return value.